# In Qt I am trying to paint over a QLabel, but QPaintEngine says to be off. Details below:

Tags: c++, qt

I can currently see the dialog window, the only thing I cannot see is the label where the picture is displayed and the rectangle drawn. Now I believe is because the widget is covering the label, but I cannot think on a way to walk around it. The application output says:
`QRect(10,10 0x0)`, `0 0 0  final  0`, `QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called`, `QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1`, `QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called`, `QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0`, `type: 1, QPainter::setPen: Painter not active`, `QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active, qDebug PAINTEVENT`

my code is as follows:

This is my_qlabel.cpp

/*Uses mouse events*/

```
    #include "my_qlabel.h"
    #include <QMouseEvent>
    #include <QPaintEvent>

    my_qlabel::my_qlabel(QWidget *parent) :
        QLabel (parent)
    {
        x = NULL;
        y = NULL;

    }//constructor

    void my_qlabel::mouseMoveEvent (QMouseEvent *e)
    {
        this->x = e->x();
        this->y = e->y();

        emit mouse_pos();
    }//mouseMoveEvent

    void my_qlabel::mouseReleaseEvent (QMouseEvent *e)
    {
        this-> x = e->x ();
        this-> y = e->y ();
        emit mouse_release();
    }//mouseReleaseEvent

    void my_qlabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)
    {

        emit mouse_pressed ();

    }//mousePressEvent


    void my_qlabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pa)
    {
        this->parentWidget ();
        this->lower ();

        emit mouse_rectangle ();
        pa->accept ();      //accepts rect in pic
    }//paintevent

    void my_qlabel::leaveEvent(QEvent *)
    {

        emit mouse_left();
    }//leaveEvent
```

below is my dialog.cpp:

/*Makes connections between my_qlabel and dialog.
        */

```
    #include "dialog.h"
    #include "ui_dialog.h"
    #include "my_qlabel.h"
    #include <QPainter>
    #include <QEvent>

    Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
        QDialog(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Dialog)
    {
         InitialX = 0;
         InitialY = 0;
         Height = 0;
         Width = 0;

        ui->setupUi(this);

        connect(ui-> lblMouse, SIGNAL(mouse_pos()),                     this, SLOT(mouse_current_pos()));
        connect(ui-> lblMouse, SIGNAL(mouse_pressed()),               this, SLOT(mouse_pressed()));
    //    connect(ui-> lblMouse, SIGNAL(mouse_pressed()),               this, SLOT(paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)));
        connect(ui-> lblMouse, SIGNAL(mouse_release()),                this, SLOT(mouse_release()));
        connect(ui-> lblMouse, SIGNAL(mouse_left()),                      this, SLOT(mouse_left()));
        connect (ui->lblMouse,SIGNAL(mouse_rectangle()),              this,SLOT(mouse_rectangle()));

        //MUST: create function for clear rectangle
        //connect(ui-> ClearSelection, SIGNAL(rectangle_clear()),       this, SLOT(mouse_left()));
        /*delete rectangle points and update paint*/
    }

    Dialog::~Dialog() { delete ui;} //deconstruct

    /* Generate mouse position on real time in the label of X and Y*/
    void Dialog::mouse_current_pos ()
    {
        ui->lblMouse_Current_Pos->setText(QString
                                          (" X = %1 , Y = %2")
                                        .arg(ui->lblMouse->x)/*%1*/
                                        .arg(ui->lblMouse->y));/*%2*/
    qDebug()<<"qDebug MOUSE_CURRENT_POS \n";
    }//mouse_current_pos()

    /*  Uses mouse event to START rectangle paint event*/
    void Dialog::mouse_pressed()
    {
        ui->lblMouse_Current_Event->setText(QString
                                            ("Mouse pressed at location %1 and %2!!!")
                                            .arg(ui->lblMouse->x)       //%1
                                            .arg(ui->lblMouse->y));    //%2

        /*Sets location of X and Y when is pressed*/
            InitialX = ui->lblMouse->x;
            InitialY = ui->lblMouse->y;
            qDebug()<<"UPDATE OF MOUSE_PRESSED \n";
        update();

    }   //mouse_pressed()

    /*Uses release mouse event to END rectangle paint event*/
    void Dialog::mouse_release()
    {
        ui->lblMouse_Current_Event->setText(QString
                                            ("Mouse released at location %1 and %2!!!")
                                            .arg(ui->lblMouse->x)   /*%1*/
                                            .arg(ui->lblMouse->y));/*%2*/

            /*Sets location of width and height when is released*/
            Width=  ui->lblMouse->x - InitialX;
            Height= ui->lblMouse->y - InitialY;
            qDebug()<<Width<<" final "<<Height;

            qDebug()<<"qDebug MOUSE_RELEASE \n";
            update();
    }//mouse_release()

    /*Mouse finds the cursor out of mouse area*/
    void Dialog::mouse_left()
    {
        ui->lblMouse_Current_Event->setText("Mouse Left :( !!");

        qDebug()<<"qDebug MOUSE_LEFT \n";
    }//mouse_left()

    void Dialog::mouse_rectangle()
    /*PaintEvent paint rectangle*/
    //!!!!!Runs good: Paints a rectangle and is adjusted!!!!
    //void Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pa)
    {
       // this->raise ();
        QRect rectangle
                (InitialX,InitialY,     //Initial point of rectangle at press event
                 Width, Height);      //Final point of rectangle at release event

        rectangle.adjust (10,10,10,10);

        qDebug()<<rectangle;
        qDebug()<<InitialX<<InitialY<<Width<<" final "<<Height;

        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.begin (this);
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::red,    //Propierties of rectangle
                            2.0,
                            Qt::DotLine,
                            Qt::SquareCap,
                            Qt::MiterJoin));
        painter.drawRect(rectangle);

        qDebug()<<"qDebug PAINTEVENT \n";
    }//paintEvent
```

Hopefully I have made my self clear, I want to draw on the qlabel, but I can't. If you can tell me how to fix the code in an explicit manner would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure what you were trying to do, but overriding the paintEvent and not painting anything seems like a bad idea to me.  What happens if you don't accept the event and call QLabel::paintEvent instead

Comment: Nothing, as the base class is dialog. I original had it working implementing the paintevent in the dialog file; however, the label was in front and the rectangle was on the back, which does not help since the purpose of the app is to select a portion of the pixels of a picture using the label.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see is, that you call a drawing function of a different class to draw in that different class by an emit in my_qlabels `paintEvent`.

If a widget receives the `paintEvent` only that widget can be drawn. An only in that class works `QPainter p(this)`.

In your case, my_qlabel has the `paintEvent` but you "call" mouse_rectangle of the Dialog class to draw on the Dialog. But Dialog is not ready for painting. Hence the `Paint device returned engine == 0` issue.

If your label shows a picture your label needs to do the drawing on itself to mark an area on the pic. and the label would be placed in the dialog. Within that `paintEvent`, at the beginning, you should call QLabel::paintEvent(event) to let the label do the picture painting. Your drawing will than be on top of that picture.

It is important that you draw in the `paintEvent` of the label on the label itself.

You may still use another function but you must pass along the pointer of my_qlabel and create the QPainter with that pointer (e.g. `QPainter p(label)` instead of `QPainter p(this)`).

So you could pass `this` on my_qlabel along with the emit, like `emit mounse_rectangle(this)` if you alter the signal and slot the accept `QWidget *` as argument. Though, I'd prefer calling any function directly from a paintEvent instead of using the signal and slot mechanism which is may introduce a considerable overhead in terms of performance and reduces code clarity.

Comment: Okay, Aaron I am trying to do that... I think. I have the paintevent in my_qlabel class, in the mousepress function in dialog I have ui->lblMouse.... I dont how to pass the event to work in here. I am getting errors.

Comment: Also, the approach with the two classes is far more complex and entangled than necessary. Try to use only the mouseEvents and paintEvents in your label class to get the work done. The `Dialog` doesn't need to do any work.